# Setting request timeout with Netflix Feign and Hystrix

Tags: hystrix, netflix-feign

I'm creating a REST client using Feign.  I've got my calls working, but I want to add some timeout support, and I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to do that.

Feign's documentation says "to use Hystrix with Feign, add the Hystrix module to your classpath. Then use the HystrixFeign builder."  Ok, so now I've got this:

```
service = HystrixFeign.builder()
                    .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                    .target(ProjectService.class, URL_TO_BE_MOVED_TO_PROPS);
```

Now all of my methods are returning HystrixCommands, which I can execute or queue, but I still can't see how to configure them.

The Hystrix wiki (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration) says that configuration should be added into the HystrixCommand constructor like this:

```
public HystrixCommandInstance(int id) {
super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"))
        .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
               .withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(500)));
this.id = id;
```

But my commands are being built/return by Feign, so I don't have access to the constructors.

One more thing worth noting is that the Feign-Hystrix readme (https://github.com/Netflix/feign/tree/master/hystrix) says "To use Hystrix with Feign, add the Hystrix module to your classpath. Then, configure Feign to use the HystrixInvocationHandler," but a Google search for HystrixInvocationHandler points me toward a non-Netflix repo.  Even if I used that, I don't see how to configure Feign to use it.

Please tell me I'm being dumb and that this is super simple, which will make me feel gladness that I'm past this issue, and shame for not being able to figure it out on my own.

TL;DR:  I want to set timeouts on requests made by my Feign client.  How do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out you can set Hystrix properties using an instance of com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager (from com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core).

Feign uses method names as HystrixCommandKeys, so you can access their properties using those names:

```
    ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command." + methodName + ".execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", 1500);
```

This is assuming you've used HystrixFeign to construct your client, which wraps each call in HystrixCommand objects.

To simplify, I created a loop of my methods so I could apply the timeout service-wide:

```
private void configureHystrix() {
    Method[] methods = ProjectService.class.getMethods();

    String methodName;
    for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        methodName = methods[i].getName();
        ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty(String.format("hystrix.command.%s.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", methodName), config.getTimeoutInMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I set the default instead of a specific method. `ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", 5000);`

Comment: Where exactly did you run this line of code? No matter what I set this to, the timeout is still 1000ms on all my feign clients.

Comment: My 'configureHystrix()' method is run right after I use HystrixFeign to construct my proxy:

        serviceProxy = HystrixFeign.builder().client(new OkHttpClient())
                .target(ProjectServiceProxy.class, config.getHostURL());

        configureHystrix();

Comment: If your methods have arguments, they are part of the name, like `hystrix.command.ProjectService#someMethod(String).execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds`, otherwise the settings don't work.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I managed to set Hystrix timeout as follows:

```
HystrixFeign.builder()
   .setterFactory(getSetterFactory())
   .target(...);

// copy-paste feign.hystrix.SetterFactory.Default, just add andCommandPropertiesDefaults
private SetterFactory getSetterFactory() {
        return (target, method) ->  {
            String groupKey = target.name();
            String commandKey = Feign.configKey(target.type(), method);
            return HystrixCommand.Setter
                .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(groupKey))
                .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(commandKey))
                .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                    .withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(15000));
        };
    }
```